# Cannot install composer on OS X Yosemite the proper way

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, composer-php, osx-yosemite

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/2qa2qj/spent_4_days_trying_to_install_laravel_nope/). I need to install Laravel but I can not get pass through Composer.

Running a line like `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` is relatively easy.

I also moved it: `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`. I have added the PATH (`export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin”`) by editing my .bash_profile, but no results. I can't get it to work.

Is there anyone who knows how to install composer properly?

Comment: what is the error you are getting? whats not working? http://www.abeautifulsite.net/installing-composer-on-os-x/

Comment: That isn't really a tutorial, and the most important part of making Composer work on the command line by using `composer` is to add the X flag on that file: `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer`. I think that's missing in that text.

Comment: the error is that i cannot access composer by simply typing the word "composer" on the terminal.

Comment: @Sven which text are you referring to please? the PATH? if so, what is the correct line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you execute command?

```
export ~/.bash_profile
```

after editing this file (also reboot can be as alternative)?
Of course as quick hack you can use either `php ~/.composer/vendor/bin/composer`
or write hardcoded alias in ~/.bash_profile:

```
alias composer="~/.composer/vendor/bin/composer"
```

and after editing do not forget to execute `export ~/.bash_profile`

also check permissions if your current user can execute this file

Comment: I tried the alias part and I get "not valid identifier" `export ~/.bash_profile` not a valid identifier either.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate all the answers above. They all helped to a final answer.
It seems that creating an alias inside the .bash_profile with the right path was solution. As of right now I can type "composer" and it will run.
The route points directly to where my composer.phar is currently installed.
A reboot was necessary as well.

```
alias composer="usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar"
```

Comment: Well, seeing your "solution" explains why nothing worked. That alias probably should read `"/usr/local/bin..."` (with a slash in front of the path), and it should not read `composer/composer.phar` at the end, because that means you created a folder named `composer` where you should have put the downloaded and renamed `composer.phar` with that name - like the command from your tutorial suggested: `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

Comment: yeah but when I type "composer" it says "no such a file directory" I have not been able to install composer properly therefore not able to install laravel.